# Java: First item of Array do not display correctly

Tags: java, twitter, arraylist

I need to compare words to tweets and count how many times they appear on text.
I used two for cycle to compare ArrayList with words and ArrayList with tweets but the first word of ArrayList with words don't display correctly and don't want to count.
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjaNz.png%C2%B4)
It is supposed to champions word count twice

My code is:

Read txt with words and save on arraylist

```
public ArrayList <String> fread(String dir) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(dir));
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (s.hasNext()){
        list.add(s.next().toLowerCase());
    }
    s.close();
return list;
}
```

Get Tweets and save them on arraylist

```
public ArrayList<String> showTimeLine() throws TwitterException {
    List<Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline(new Paging (1,200));
    ArrayList<String> allTweets=new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Status status : statuses) {
        allTweets.add(status.getText().replaceAll("https[^\\s]+","").toLowerCase());
    }        
    return allTweets;
}
```

Compare two arrays:

```
public ArrayList<String> result(ArrayList<String>tweets, ArrayList<String> palavras){
         for (int i = 0; i <palavras.size() ; i++) {
            int count = 0;
             for (int j = 0; j <tweets.size() ; j++) {
            if (tweets.get(j).contains(palavras.get(i))){
                count++;
            }
        }
        numero.add(count);
        result.add(palavras.get(i));
                }
      return result;
}
```

And print

```
for (int i = 0; i <result.size() ; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%40s",result.get(i)+"        "+numero.get(i)+"\n");

    }
```

Static ArrayList:

```
     static ArrayList<Integer> numero = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     static ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Thanks ! :)

Comment: Your printf statement is extremely limited, and you're not using it to its full capacity. You should be using at least two `%xd` statements where x is an int, and a `%n` at the end all within the initial String and surrounded by quotes, in other words within the first printf parameter. The second and 3rd parameters should be the two `get(i)` statements.

Comment: Can you please provide a small sample that demonstrates the error?

Comment: I solved the problem. I don't know why but If I create a txt file with windows notepad I have this "bug" but If I create a txt file with Notepad ++ it runs great without any problem.
@HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method

```
public ArrayList<String> result(ArrayList<String>tweets, ArrayList<String> palavras){
     for (int i = 0; i <palavras.size() ; i++) {
        int count = 0;
         for (int j = 0; j <tweets.size() ; j++) {
        if (tweets.get(j).contains(palavras.get(i))){
            count++;
        }
    }
    numero.add(count);
    result.add(palavras.get(i));
            }
  return result;
```

}

Your if-statement finds a single result and then ends.  You can fix this like so

```
public static ArrayList<String> result(ArrayList<String>tweets, ArrayList<String> palavras){
    for (int i = 0; i <palavras.size() ; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <tweets.size() ; j++) {
            boolean isDone = false; //NEW
            int tweetCharIter = 1; //NEW
            while (!isDone){ //NEW
                if (tweets.get(j).substring(tweetCharIter).contains(palavras.get(i))){ //ALTERED
                    tweetCharIter += tweets.get(j).substring(tweetCharIter).indexOf(palavras.get(i)) +1; //ALTERED
                    count++;
                } else { //NEW
                    isDone = true; //NEW
                }
            }
        }
        numero.add(count);
        result.add(palavras.get(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Same output as original :(